# How to limit the # of lines AND characters per line in Google Forms Regex

Tags: regex, google-forms

I need to set up a paragraph box in Google Forms that limits responses to 5 lines with no more than 59 characters per line.

I've tried a number of different versions, but what I have right now is:

`^(?:[^.{0,59}$\r\n]*(?:\r\n?|\n)){0,4}[^\r\n]*$`

I've also tried:

`\A(^.{0,59}$\r?\n?){0,4}\z`

`^(?:[^\r\n]*(?:\r\n?|\n)){0,4}[^\r\n]*$` works fine to limit the number of lines, but I can't figure out how to limit the characters per line at the same time. My current code fails with anything more than one line and does not limit the character count of that one line.

I've never used Regex before, so I'm just trying to understand and piece together code I've found from other people, but nothing quite works. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Try `^.{0,59}(?:\r?\n.{0,59}){0,4}$`

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. If you have a second, could you explain briefly why that formula works? I'd like to understand the logic and why I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
^.{0,59}(?:\r?\n.{0,59}){0,4}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iRkdVt/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E.%7B0%2C59%7D(%3F%3A%5Cr%3F%5Cn.%7B0%2C59%7D)%7B0%2C4%7D%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `.{0,59}` - 0 to 59 chars other than line break chars
- `(?:\r?\n.{0,59}){0,4}` - zero to four repetitions of

  - `\r?\n` - an optional CR (carriage return) followed with a newline char (LF)
  - `.{0,59}` - 0 to 59 chars other than line break chars
- `$` - end of string.